# getting error during omake build 0.9.8.5-3

Tags: omake

I am trying to build omake 0.9.8.5-3 but getting following error. So please help me fix it.

```
    ocamlc -thread -c omake_gen_magic.ml
```

**File "omake_gen_magic.ml", line 90, characters 14-33:
Error: Unbound module Lm_string_util**
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\OCaml\bin\ocamlc.EXE' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Answer (score 0):

In src/Makefile.nt, some needs to change. It is because it doesn't make a proper Makefile.dep.

This is the original.

```
#
# Create a dependency file
#
Makefile.dep: $(ALLFILES)
    $(OCAMLDEP) $(OCAMLINCLUDES) *.ml *.mli > Makefile.dep
```

This is the modified.

```
#
# Create a dependency file
#
Makefile.dep: $(ALLFILES)
    $(OCAMLDEP) $(OCAMLINCLUDES) $?.ml $?.mli > Makefile.dep
```